# I'm trying to design an algorithm that sorts given words alphabetically like a dictionary but it seems that I can't progress any further

Tags: c

First of all, I'm sorry if this isn't an appropriate question to ask. I only recently started to learn to code so it could be something obvious that I'm missing, I'm sorry about that too.

When given the words "seal", "snake", "lion"; the output is "seal sion lnake". I tried analyzing the algorithm by hand but couldn't figure out the problem. If someone could help me out, I'd really appreciate that.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    int i;
    int j;
    int k=0;
    int l;
    char word[100][100];
    char tmp;
    
    printf("Enter the number of words ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the word ");
        scanf("%s", word[i]);
    }
    
    for(i=0; i<n-1; i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1; j<n; j++)
        {
            while(word[i][k]==word[j][k])
            {
                k=k+1;
            }
            if(word[i][k]>word[j][k])
            {
                for(l=k; l<100; l++)
                {
                    tmp=word[i][l];
                    word[i][l]=word[j][l];
                    word[j][l]=tmp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%s ", word[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorting any kind of array in C is spelled: `qsort`

Comment: You need to reset `k` (add `k = 0;`) at the beginning of the `j` loop.

Comment: @4386427: reinventing the wheel -- or rather, building slightly square wheels :) -- is a good activity for newbies... as is finding out about the C library features!

Comment: @pmg Agree that it can be good to look into how you can implement the library functions yourself. But that's not the way to start learning C. Start out by using `qsort`, `strcmp`, etc. and once you know how to use them, it's can be good to implement them...

Comment: Probably not directly related to your current problem, but you *must* not write `scanf("%s", word[i]);`  If the input stream has a string longer than 100 bytes, it will overflow your buffer and your program will exhibit undefined behavior.  Instead, write `scanf("%99s", word[i])`, check the value returned by scanf, and verify that it did not truncate a word in the input.

Comment: Just some addition to the answer given by `pmg`. To prevent such bugs and improve readability, it is a good practice to declare variables in the innermost block where they are used.

Comment: @HAL9000: In principle, you are right. But there are also cases where you can't do this (for example, if your code has to be compiled with a compiler that only supports ANSI C).

Comment: @Xaver, that is very hypothetical, unless you have a time machine. If there are still any platforms that are ANSI C only, it is safe to assume that in the the time a c-beginner gets to a point where he is able to write production code, those platforms will either be gone, or support more modern C.  Anyway, it is better to not let non-standard and obscure platform stand in the way of writing quality code. Worry about those platforms later.